# Usage of "genauer gesagt"

Tags: grammar, usage, phrase, sentence-structure

Can someone break down the structure of the following sentence in English?

> Ich lebe in Bayern, genauer gesagt in München.

Google Translate's answer makes sense: "I live in Bayern, specifically in Munich."

When can *genauer gesagt* be used? Does the following sentence makes sense?

> Ich lebe genauer gesagt in München.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Genauer* (literally: "more precisely"<sup>1</sup>) is a [comparative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative), so you always need something to compare it to or, as it's typically used, a fact that can be specified - either in the same sentence or somewhere in the context.

Taking this into account, your first example makes sense, detailing a specific place in Bavaria:

> Ich lebe in Bayern, genauer gesagt in München.

Your second sentence is not wrong grammar-wise, but from a logic point of view it can't stand *alone*. To make sense we must assume a preceding sentence like (random example):

> Ich bin vor einigen Jahren nach Deutschland gezogen. Ich lebe genauer gesagt in München.

---

<sup>1</sup> Other translations / typical phrases for *genauer gesagt* are for example:

- to be precise
- namely
- specifically
- to be exact

Comment: What is the purpose of gesagt?  Could one say:

Ich lebe in Bayern, genauer in München.

Comment: @Amaziah, yes strictly speaking the "gesagt" is optional, but it's customary. Somewhat like a set phrase. I would even use it when it's absolutely clear that I'm not talking, e.g. in a letter.

Comment: What is the purpose of “speaking” in “strictly speaking”? (Apologies if it was already intentional and my bluntness ruined it.)

Comment: You used the expression “strictly speaking” and I was amused by the parallel to the German expression under discussion.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Aahhh! No pun intended, but good catch, thanks! (Would that now be called a "Freudian joke"?)

Comment: the "literal" translation would be more like "said more precisely". That way the question about "gesagt" wouldn't have arisen. (oh arisen, I like thee). Also, "Strictly speaking it's optional but it's customary". What does that mean? I can totally not skip it because that would sound quite odd/wrongish. So how is it optional? And by what "strictness".. grammar strictness? I'm nitpicking here but I think you can handle it :)

Comment: @Emanuel: You can say _in Bayern, genauer in München_, so the _gesagt_ is optional.

Comment: @chirlu... "Ein Kollege, genauer gesagt Thomas,..." absolutely doesn't work without "gesagt" for me.